# html, head, body tags in TINYMCE editor - SEO issues

Tags: html, seo, tinymce, meta-tags

I am working with a client that requires for my HTML pages to be pasted into a TINYMCE Editor (Elements Local Server).

When I tried pasting the entire HTML page, it did not work and would not even show up.  Once I stripped it down to the basic html (omitting html, head, body tags) it worked fine.

My question is, as an SEO company I'm needing to effectively place title tags, description, keywords, etc. but now that I stripped down the code, I can't really place these anymore correct?  Since there isn't a `<head>` tag anymore...

I haven't tested yet but I might be able to only have the `<head>` tags and remove the `<html>` and `<body>` tag but i'm not sure.

If possible, will search engines allow ONLY a `<head>` tag at the top of the code instead.

Has anyone ever pasted a full html page into TINYMCE editor?

Comment: why would you paste an entire HTML page to an editor?
You need to use a server apply diffrent editors for each part of the page to be edited, and "ANDDDD, its gone".

Comment: I may not be explaining well.  We've built dozens of html pages on a different server and they now require those pages to be on THEIR server.  The ONLY way to build a page on their server is through a TINYMCE editor.  It's a gateway where they must approve each page built.  We copy+paste whatever code from previous html pages into the editor however possible.  I read the tutorial below but they don't explain limitations or capabilities of adding SEO features through TINYMCE.  Thanks.

Comment: TINYMCE is an HTML editor. nothing more. for what you are requesting, you need a server side code. Oh almost forgot, IT HAS NOTHING TO DO WITH SEO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tinymce is not a textarea, but a contenteditable iframe. So you will be able to write things to the head.
It is true that you will have to strip out html, body and head tags first (because they are already there), but you can save the head tag and write its content to the tinymce iframes head.

Here is the way how to get the tinymce iframe:

```
var tinymce_iframe = $(your_editor_id + "_ifr").get(0);
```

Comment: Thank you for helping and addressing the actual question.  Brilliant!

Answer (score -3):

You may visit this site: http://www.siteavenger.com/image-uploads-with-tinymce.php

Good luck